# C Sharp: How can use an object, having only it's name from a string?

Tags: c#

I know that the title is not suggestive, so I will try to explaining using some code:

```
public static Boolean IsIt(String nameObject1, String nameObject1) 
{
    //here I want to verify if nameObject1 is of type nameObject2
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by object name? Are you talking about a WinForms Control?

Comment: Sorry, not possible like that.

Comment: You should never find yourself in a situation where you need to do this. You're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string representation of the name, you can use `Type.GetType` to get a `Type` representation, then you can check if one object is assignable from the other (I assume this is what you want, although I cannot be sure). In the example below, I have created `class FooBase` and `class Foo : FooBase`

```
static bool IsIt(string nameObject1, string nameObject2)
{
    Type type1 = Type.GetType(nameObject1);
    Type type2 = Type.GetType(nameObject2);
    return type2.IsAssignableFrom(type1);
}

static void Main()
{
    bool b = IsIt(typeof(Foo).FullName, typeof(FooBase).FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you'd have to have a reference to the object in some list that you can look it up by name (for example, in a `Dictionary<string, object>`), and then compare the two objects.

```
private static Dictionary<string, object> objDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

public static Boolean IsIt(String nameObject1, String nameObject2) 
{
    return objDictionary[nameObject1].ReferenceEquals(objDictionary[nameObject2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to implement the interface that you proposed.
If you could change it, we could give it a try:

```
public static bool IsIt(object instance, Type type)
{
    return instance.GetType() == type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that nameObject2 contains a type name like "System.String" for example?  If so, this would work.

```
public static Boolean IsIt(String nameObject1, String nameObject2) 
{
    Type t = Type.GetType(nameObject2);
    return (nameObject1.GetType() == t);
}
```